# HQL query analog for the SQL expression

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

There are two entities. **Meeting** and **Topic**  (corresponding tables are **Meetings** and **Topics**)

Where one meeting may contain a set of topics.

Example table structure is as follows:

[image: tables]

In my java code `Meeting` class has the following declaration:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "MeetingTopics",
joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "meetingId")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "topicId")})    
@Expose
private Set<Topic> topicsList;
```

I want to get a list of meetings (with topics inside of them), where `someTopicField` of a topic is equal to a particular value, let say it is `11`

SQL expression to get what I want looks like that:

```
SELECT meetings.meetingcomment, 
       topics.topicsubject, 
       topics.sometopicfield 
FROM   topics 
       INNER JOIN (meetings 
                   INNER JOIN meetingtopics 
                           ON meetings.meetingid = meetingtopics.meetingid) 
               ON topics.topicid = meetingtopics.topicid 
WHERE  ( topics.sometopicfield  = 11 );
```

But I would like to use HQL expression to solve this task, and I did not figure it out, how could I do that.

I've read [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins) but did not understand, how to apply those examples to my question.

What HQL expression will do the same as above described SQL does?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select m.meetingcomment,
       t.topicsubject,
       t.sometopicfield
from Meeting as m
inner join m.topicsList as t
with t.sometopicfield = 11
```

If you need only the `Meeting` class fields the hql is:

```
select m from Meeting as m
inner join m.topicsList as t
with t.sometopicfield = 11
```

And you get a list of `Meeting` objects.

Comment: when I invoke `from Meeting as m
inner join m.topicsList as t
with t.sometopicfield = 11` I get a mixed list with Topic and Meeting objects inside. Is there a way to get a list with only Meeting objects?

Comment: No. if you need to select fields from both `Meeting` and `Topic` as in your example. Yes, if you restrict to only `Meeting` fields in the query. Updated the answer.

Comment: Sorry, if I was not clear. I want to get all meetings (list of `Meeting` object) which contain topics with `sometopicfield = 11`. Expression `from Meeting as m
inner join m.topicsList as t with t.sometopicfield = 11` returns list of Topic and Meeting objects inside.

Comment: No. I think I understood correctly your need. if you don't specify the projection fields to be from both `Meeting` and `Topic`: `select m.meetingcomment, t.topicsubject, t.sometopicfield` the returned `List` should contain only `Meeting` objects.

Comment: Thank you. Just checked updated expression for query `from Meeting as m inner join m.topicsList as t where t.sometopicfield = 11`. Still returns a list with different objects. List contains Topic and Meeting class instances.

Comment: Every item of returned list is an two-element array. Where the first item of this array is Topic class instance and the second one is Meeting class instance.

Comment: Here is [the link](http://i.imgur.com/gc9IlrF.png) to the debugger screenshot. `abc` variable stores query result.

Comment: That's true. My fault. Slightly updated the answer: you need to specify the `select m`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
select meeting.meetingcomment,
       topic.topicsubject,
       topic.sometopicfield
from Meeting meeting
inner join meeetings.topicsList as topic
where topic.sometopicfield = 11
```

Comment: when I invoke `from Meeting meeting
inner join meeetings.topicsList as topic
where topic.sometopicfield = 11` I get a mixed list with Topic and Meeting objects inside. Is there a way to get a list with only Meeting objects?